# com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid operator IN for PRIMARY KEY part

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have cassandra 2.1.15. 
I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE ks_mobapp.messages (
    pair_id text,
    belong_to text,
    message_id timeuuid,
    cli_time bigint,
    sender text,
    text text,
    time bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY ((pair_id, belong_to), message_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id DESC)
```

I was trying to delete multiple record as

```
        instances.getCqlSession().execute(QueryBuilder.delete()
                .from(AppConstants.KEYSPACE, "messages")
                .where(QueryBuilder.eq("pair_id", pairId))
                .and(QueryBuilder.eq("belong_to", currentUser.value("userId")))
                .and(QueryBuilder.in("message_id", msgId)));
```

I am getting error:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid operator IN for PRIMARY KEY part message_id
```

Then I tried:

```
        Session session = instances.getCqlSession();
        PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("DELETE FROM ks_mobApp.messages WHERE pair_id = ? AND belong_to = ? AND message_id = ?;");
        Iterator<String> iterator = msgId.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            try {
                session.executeAsync(statement.bind(pairId, currentUser.value("userId"), UUID.fromString(iterator.next())));
            } catch(Exception ex) {

            }
        }
```

Its working nice. Is this the correct way? I can't use IN for same partition key ?

Comment: which cassandra version are you using ?

Comment: check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740374/cassandra-update-and-delete-in-clustering-column-using-in-operator

Answer (score 0):

DELETE in Query only supported for partition key.

> Delete IN relation is only supported for partition key)

Answer (score 0):

There are some WHERE clause restrictions for the UPDATE and DELETE statements in cassandra 2.x

more specifically you can only use the IN operator on `the last partition key column`. So in your case the last partition column is `belong_to`. so `IN` can only be used on that column.

However these limitation are removed in cassandra 3.0. and it will allow

> IN to be specified on any partition key column
>
> IN to be specified on any clustering column

Here is the patch https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6237

Read this also http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause

Comment: how about the other solution that i hv mentioned

Comment: In the other solution you are not using IN right ? you are only using '=' which is allowed on clustering columns.

Comment: I had read that this solution is scalable as all deletion reqtest will be distributed among all node

Comment: which solution?

Comment: using executeAsncy than using IN https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/

Comment: yes. sending requests to each node individually instead of using IN is preferable.